# Create a menu for user options

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have designed this panel with an avatar on it. What I want to do is have a little menu popup when you click on the avatar picture that would have options like, go to profile, add friend, pm this person. But I am not sure how to go about it as I am still new to jquery and css .

So I am looking to the community to see if I can get some Ideas or help on how to achieve this.

this is the fiddle I currently have setup [Example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0o6ysxq9/8/)

```
#recent-posts{
    background: #D2C198;
}
#posts{
    /*max-height: 90%;*/
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.posts-container{
    background-color: #D2C198;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.card-header{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    padding: 0.35rem 1.25rem;
}
.forum-badge{
    float: left;
}
.forum-badge img, .last-poster-avatar img,
.reply-poster-avatar img, .reply-poster-guild-crest img{
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.forum-badge img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.divider{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.post-details{
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.last-poster{
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-left: 14px;
}
.post-description{
    padding-left: 30px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 86px;
}
.last-poster-avatar{
    margin-right: 12px;
}
.last-poster-avatar img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.post-statistics, .reply-poster-guild-detail{
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
.reply-poster-avatar, .reply-poster-detail, .reply-poster-guild-crest, .reply-poster-guild-detail{
    display: inline-block;
}
.reply-poster-avatar{
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
}
.reply-poster-avatar img{
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}
.reply-poster-detail{
    /*width: 38.7%;*/
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: left;
}
.reply-poster-detail div{
    text-align: left;
}
.reply-poster-guild-crest{
    padding-top: 18px;
}
.reply-poster-guild-crest img{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
.reply-poster-guild-detail,.reply-poster-detail{
    top: 11px;
    position: relative;
}
.reply-detail-container{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.replier-avatar-detail {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.replier-avatar-detail,
.reply-poster-guild-detail {
    max-width: 50%;
    min-width: 45%;
}

<div id="recent-posts" class="card">
<div class="card-body">
    <div id="posts">
        <div class="card posts-container" id="a">
            <div class="card-header post" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#post-replies" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="post-replies">
                <div class="forum-badge">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/6QjQvk77/poedelve_copy.jpg" alt="Path of Exile">
                </div>
                <div class="post-container">
                    <div class="post-description">
                        <h5 class="mb-0"><div><!-- Post text goes here-->Sulphite WP farming is stupid as hell</div></h5>
                        <div class="divider"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-details">
                        <div class="last-poster">
                            <div class="last-poster-avatar">
                                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/NfHQ0y7r/img_avatar.png" alt="Last Poster Avatar">
                            </div>
                            <div class="poster-detail-sm">
                                <div>Harold</div>
                                <div>3 hours ago</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-statistics">
                            <div class="post-replies">
                                Replies <span>999</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="post-views">
                                Views <span>999,999</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- replies section -->
            <div id="post-replies" class="collapse replies-container" aria-labelledby="a list of replies" data-parent="#posts"><!-- New replies must have dash and postnumber following post-replies e.g post-replies-223333 -->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!-- replies -->
                    <div id="replies"><!-- New replies must have dash and postnumber following replies e.g replies-223333 -->
                        <div class="card replies-container">
                            <div class="card-header reply" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#reply-content" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="reply-content"><!-- New replies must have dash and postnumber following reply-content e.g reply-content-223333 -->
                                <div class="reply-detail-container">
                                    <div class="replier-avatar-detail">
                                        <div class="reply-poster-avatar">
                                            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/cJHx0FDd/female-default.png" alt="Poster's Avatar">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="reply-poster-detail">
                                            <div>Aurianna</div>
                                            <div>2 hours ago</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="reply-poster-guild-crest">
                                        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/yYH7k1fQ/Dragon-design.jpg" alt="Guild Crest">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="reply-poster-guild-detail">
                                        <div>House of Myrmadons</div>
                                        <div>Rank: Officer</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="reply-content" class="reply-message collapse" aria-labelledby="reply-header" data-parent="#replies"><!-- New replies must have dash and postnumber following reply-content e.g reply-content-223333 -->
                                <div class="card-body poster-body">
                                    Reply Content Here
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card replies-container">
                            <div class="card-header reply" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#reply-content1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="reply-content1"><!-- New replies must have dash and postnumber following reply-content e.g reply-content-223333 -->
                                <div class="reply-detail-container">
                                    <div class="replier-avatar-detail">
                                        <div class="reply-poster-avatar">
                                            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/cJHx0FDd/female-default.png" alt="Poster's Avatar">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="reply-poster-detail">
                                            <div>Chris</div>
                                            <div>2 hours ago</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="reply-poster-guild-crest">
                                        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/yYH7k1fQ/Dragon-design.jpg" alt="Guild Crest">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="reply-poster-guild-detail">
                                        <div>House of GGG</div>
                                        <div>Rank: CEO</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="reply-content1" class="reply-message collapse" aria-labelledby="reply-header" data-parent="#replies"><!-- New replies must have dash and postnumber following reply-content e.g reply-content-223333 -->
                                <div class="card-body poster-body">
                                    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus
                                        accusantium amet autem corporis, deserunt eaque facilis laborum magni nobis
                                        officia officiis optio quibusdam, quisquam repellat velit. Molestiae non
                                        temporibus voluptatum!
                                    </div>
                                    <div>Ad consequuntur corporis cum cumque dolorem hic incidunt iure natus
                                        necessitatibus nihil obcaecati officiis quas quibusdam quis quo repellat
                                        reprehenderit ut, vel vitae, voluptatum. Accusamus ad obcaecati odio vero
                                        voluptas.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card replies-container">
                            <div class="card-header reply" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#reply-content3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="reply-content3"><!-- New replies must have dash and postnumber following reply-content e.g reply-content-223333 -->
                                <div class="reply-detail-container">
                                    <div class="replier-avatar-detail">
                                        <div class="reply-poster-avatar">
                                            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/cJHx0FDd/female-default.png" alt="Poster's Avatar">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="reply-poster-detail">
                                            <div>Chris</div>
                                            <div>2 hours ago</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="reply-poster-guild-crest">
                                        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/yYH7k1fQ/Dragon-design.jpg" alt="Guild Crest">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="reply-poster-guild-detail">
                                        <div>House of GGG</div>
                                        <div>Rank: CEO</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="reply-content3" class="reply-message collapse" aria-labelledby="reply-header" data-parent="#replies"><!-- New replies must have dash and postnumber following reply-content e.g reply-content-223333 -->
                                <div class="card-body poster-body">
                                    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus
                                        accusantium amet autem corporis, deserunt eaque facilis laborum magni nobis
                                        officia officiis optio quibusdam, quisquam repellat velit. Molestiae non
                                        temporibus voluptatum!
                                    </div>
                                    <div>Ad consequuntur corporis cum cumque dolorem hic incidunt iure natus
                                        necessitatibus nihil obcaecati officiis quas quibusdam quis quo repellat
                                        reprehenderit ut, vel vitae, voluptatum. Accusamus ad obcaecati odio vero
                                        voluptas.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End replies -->
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

if anyone can take some time to look at it and help with some ideas or solutions on how I could get this done that would be excellent !

Answer (score 0):

You can find some sample here :

- https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/account-in-navbar
- https://www.labw3.com/2014/08/round-avatar-with-drop-down-profiles-menu-code.html
- https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/stylish-custom-user-settings-dropdown-menu-with-css